# ERROR: DexGuard Gradle plugin: Android Gradle plugin version is not supported. (3.5.0), supported versions include [2.3.0:3.4.*]

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

[image]
i am getting an error while create released build recently i have updated android studio new version 3.5 after that this error is appearing and build failed but created build too so any one already suffered and fixed it so please tell me one more thing is that i have implemented dexgaurd when i update gradle version so it does not allow dex gaurd plugin too...

i have changed the gradle build tool version version and clean project and make project but not working

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the DexGuard gradle plugin that you are using, you can't use

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```

Just use:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer
i have changed the version according to latest gradle support in documents 3.3.0 
so its working for me

Comment: dexguard's latest supported android gradle plugin version is `3.6.0` which IMO is very limiting if you wanna optimize your build.

Answer (score 0):

For dexguard 8.5.09, DexGuard plugin could be supported by Android Gradle plugin 3.5.0.
We do not need to downgrade the Android Gradle plugin version from 3.5.0 to 3.4.0.

I fix it by the following:

```
Fix the sync error

diff --git a/build.gradle b/build.gradle
index 1df386c..9273764 100644
--- a/build.gradle
+++ b/build.gradle
@@ -27,7 +27,6 @@ buildscript {
         classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:$jacoco_version"
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
         classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:$shadow_version"
-        classpath ":dexguard:"
         classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.8.6'
         classpath 'com.guardsquare:dexguard:8.5.09'
         classpath 'com.guardsquare:dexguard-annotations:8.5.09'
```

Comment: Which gradle plugin are you using with this dexguard version ?